# NodeJS / Etherpad: freshly installed etherpad causes TypeError

Tags: debian, node.js

I have a Debian 7 stable server and installed etherpad-lite with this tutorial [how to install etherpad-lite on debian stable](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-etherpad-lite-on-debian-wheezy/).

Everything went fine and etherpad starts without errors using:

```
service etherpad-lite start
```

But when I try to connect and do something:

```
http://my-domain.tld:9001
```

I see the etherpad page showing up with missing labels on buttons and stuff and doing pretty much nothing.

Etherpad crashes and restarts then, according to my [etherpad-lite.log](http://pastebin.com/ZKMRQZA2).

What is wrong? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I were able to fix the problem :) :)

The solution is relatively simple: the TypeError raised because of some new feature ignoring some requirements of (older) NodeJS installations.

All one has to do is either switch to development branch of etherpad and the newest commit or to one of the stable branches and a commit before December 2014.